# How many Rusted Keys do you need to get red items most of the time?

Tags: risk-of-rain-2

Having a single rusted key allows you to open rusty lockboxes, but will usually give you white items. Having more of them increases your chances at green or even red items, but I don't know at what rate. Testing a run with 1 key, I got 5 white items in a row, while i got 5 red items in a row on a run with 99 keys, but this just confirms that there is a difference, not the rate that the chances change at.

Comment: How did you get 99 keys?

Comment: @HalfEmpty Either it was a really really long run, or (more likely) they used a Shrine of Order, which "condenses" your items into a single kind.

Comment: Actually, a third option, I used cheat engine. Mostly because getting 99 of anything by hand takes forever.

Comment: @Jonathan You probably could have bypassed the need for that as well.  I believe that RoR2 has a built-in console where you can enable cheats and give yourself items.  Either that or I completely misunderstood a conversation on Discord I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [the wiki for rusted key.](https://riskofrain2.fandom.com/wiki/Rusted_Key) Based on the scaling it is functionally impossible to get 100% chance for legendary. However for 100 keys, it goes up to 80%, which is solid. With 5000 keys, the chance for legendary is 99.60%.

[image: Graph of the table below]

The full table from the wiki looks like so:

```
Keys |  Common | Uncommon | Legendary
---- | ------- | -------- | ---------
1    | 79.21%  | 19.80%   | 0.99%
2    | 64.52%  | 32.26%   | 3.23%
3    | 53.69%  | 40.27%   | 6.04%
4    | 45.45%  | 45.45%   | 9.09%
5    | 39.02%  | 48.78%   | 12.20%
6    | 33.90%  | 50.85%   | 15.25%
7    | 29.74%  | 52.04%   | 18.22%
8    | 26.32%  | 52.63%   | 21.05%
9    | 23.46%  | 52.79%   | 23.75%
10   | 21.05%  | 52.63%   | 26.32%
15   | 13.22%  | 49.59%   | 37.19%
20   | 9.09%   | 45.45%   | 45.45%
50   | 2.23%   | 27.93%   | 69.83%
100  | 0.66%   | 16.56%   | 82.78%
1000 | 0.01%   | 1.96%    | 98.03%
5000 | 0.00%   | 0.40%    | 99.60%
```

Comment: Great. Would you be able to post the whole chart from the wiki here?

Comment: Nice edit Kroltan. I looked for that graph but couldn't find it.

Comment: @AdamSpecker I made it from the table :)